# How do i trigger the event of a 'file' input button via another event?

Tags: hta

Ok peep's so the **file input** tag is very cumbersome and static, but I don't know any other way to do what it does.

Thing is.. I want to be able to split it like siamese twins, ***right down the middle***, if you'll excuse the pun...

---

```
<input id="upload_input" type="text" placeholder="Upload A File">
<button id="upload_button">Upload..</button>

<input id="hidden_input" type="file" style="display:none">
```

---

```
$('#upload_button').click(function(){
    // initiate hidden_input
})

$('#hidden_input').change(function(){
    $('#upload_input').text(
        $('#hidden_input').text()
    )
    // or upload_input.innerText = hidden_input.innerText
    // if the jQuery isn't right, I don't know much jQuery...
})
```

---

I think that explains what I'm trying to do, if not just ask away... thanks in advance!

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand your question at all ; ) Anyway, `input`s have `value` instead of `textContent`, hence `$('#upload_input').val( $('#hidden_input').val());`

Comment: dude never mind I found what i was lookin for, it was the `$().click()` event I'd been usin all along, I just ain't got round to writing an answer yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dude never mind I found what i was lookin for, it was the `$().click()` event I'd been usin all along